# XNK data is not populated in my xslt code

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

Here is my first XSLT script, not knowing anything about XMLs or how they work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">      
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE><PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
            <METADATA>
```

Mapping the XSLT to Filemaker works below

```
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="IncID" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            </METADATA>
```

Somewhere below I need to populate the FM database
The single names are being populated but the XML data is not

```
            <RESULTSET>
                <ROW>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA><xsl:value-of select="IncID"/></DATA>
                    </COL>
                </ROW>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is a short XML document, the file name will change on every upload.
NOTHING BELOW CAN CHANGE.

```
<dataSet xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/cognos/dataSet/201006">
    <dataTable>
        <id>IncidentHeader</id>
        <row>
            <IncID>286996</IncID>
            <IncNumber>ZA-RDF-0190</IncNumber>
        </row>
    </dataTable>
    <dataTable>
        <id>IncidentRequests</id>
        <row>
            <IncID>286996</IncID>
            <ResID>2412136</ResID>
            <ReqID>7820453</ReqID>
            <RootReqFlag>Yes</RootReqFlag>
        </row>
        <row>
            <IncID>286996</IncID>
            <ResID>2258222</ResID>
            <ReqID>7820454</ReqID>
            <RootReqFlag>Yes</RootReqFlag>
        </row>
    </dataTable>
</dataSet>
```

Comment: How does the output look like? Most of the output XML elements are hard coded in the XSLT, except for `IncID` element which is being accessed from an incorrect context.

Comment: The output is just a FileMaker database.

Comment: This did not work -     <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="IncID"></xsl:value-of></DATA></COL>

Comment: Which `IncID` is to be retrieved or you need all the values. The input XML also has a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/cognos/dataSet/201006"` which is not mapped in the XSLT. This may be another reason that no value is returned from XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

The XML has a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/cognos/dataSet/201006"` with which all the elements are associated. This namespace needs to be mapped in the XSLT and the elements should be accessed using the namespace prefix. Here `ns0` has been used as a prefix.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/cognos/dataSet/201006">
```

The XSLT is being matched with the document root template `/` hence when accessing any element, the complete XPath for the element needs to be specified. Depending on whether all the `IncID` elements are to be accessed or a specific `IncID` element is to be accessed, the XPath will be different.

If the output requires values of all the `IncID` elements (though the value is same, XPath will be different), you may need a `<xsl:for-each>` loop to fetch the output.

```
<RESULTSET>
    <ROW>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:dataSet/ns0:dataTable/ns0:row">
            <COL>
                <DATA><xsl:value-of select="ns0:IncID" /></DATA>
            </COL>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

The output in this case will be

```
<RESULTSET>
    <ROW>
        <COL>
            <DATA>286996</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>286996</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>286996</DATA>
        </COL>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

If only the value from the first occurrence of `IncID` is to be fetched, you may either use

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ns0:row[1]/ns0:IncID" />
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ns0:IncID[1]" />
```

The output in this case would look like

```
<RESULTSET>
    <ROW>
        <COL>
            <DATA>286996</DATA>
        </COL>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

Comment: YES it works, Thank you so very much, I would of never thought that I needed to add the namespace and the ns0 - Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're not alone. Search SO for "XSLT default namespace" and you'll find 659 other people who would never have thought it. And that's not counting the questions explicitly deleted as duplicates. Sadly it's very hard to see a way to stop countless more people falling into the same trap. Saxon tries to give you a warning if you do this, but Saxon probably tends to be used more by experienced users rather than by first-timers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to import all data into a single FileMaker table. In this case, you have to do some parsing of the source since you appear to have 2 tables in the source, IncidentHeader and IncidentRequests, each contained in identical 'dataTable' elements.
They do however share the key field IncID, which can then be used to fetch the IncNumber into the IncidentRequest data.

This should do the trick, I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/*">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" xmlns:c="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/cognos/dataSet/201006">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
            <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="{count(c:dataTable[c:id='IncidentRequests']/c:row)}" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD>
                    <xsl:attribute name="EMPTYOK">YES</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MAXREPEAT">1</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="NAME">IncNumber</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">TEXT</xsl:attribute>
                </FIELD>
                <xsl:for-each select="c:dataTable[c:id='IncidentRequests']/c:row[position()=1]/*">
                    <FIELD>
                        <xsl:attribute name="EMPTYOK">YES</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MAXREPEAT">1</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">TEXT</xsl:attribute>
                    </FIELD>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET>
                <xsl:attribute name="FOUND"><xsl:value-of select="count(c:dataTable[c:id='IncidentRequests']/c:row)"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="c:dataTable[c:id='IncidentRequests']/c:row">
                    <xsl:variable name="incid">
                        <xsl:value-of select="c:IncID"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <ROW>
                        <xsl:attribute name="MODID">0</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="RECORDID">0</xsl:attribute>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//c:dataTable[c:id='IncidentHeader']/c:row[c:IncID=$incid]/c:IncNumber"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>  
                        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                            <COL>
                                <DATA>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </DATA>
                            </COL>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```